# Open charge point protocol (OCPP) server implementation using Python Djago or Java Spring boot

Tags: python, java, django, embedded

I am programming a a PoC of OCPP server which can communicate with an EV charger using OCPP protocol, in Python Django and Java Spring boot. I was using a OCPP python package given in the link [here](https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ocpp) and I was able to create a OCPP center system using Python and make connections. My server should be able to have the method to list all connected chargers, but I could not find any documentation about this. Is this method available on the Python OCPP package [here](https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ocpp). If not, can anyone tell me how to implement this method?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over. If you have some new information then edit the original question instead.

Comment: Did you implement a Python-based server or not yet? If yes is it found on Github?

Comment: @ksa I found this on this [link](https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ocpp)

Comment: @HuyNguyen check this https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/twqukd/ocpp_python_based_server_with_fastapi_integration/ as starting point